# SelectFx is not defined

Tags: angularjs

i want to show selected value, when data come from server, if data is message1 then it selected.

html

```
     <select name="message_page" class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a message</option>                                                
        <option value="message1">message1</option>
        <option value="message2">message2</option>
        <option value="message3">message3</option>
        <option value="message4">message4</option>  
    </select>
```

angular js

```
$http.post(baseURL, {
        id:id,
        action:'SingleMessage'
   }).then(function(response){
       if(response.data.status == 1){
angular.element('[name=message_page]').val(response.data.data.message_page);
(function() {
            [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'select.cs-select' ) ).forEach( function(el) {
                new SelectFx(el);
            } );
        })();
        }
},function errorCallback(response){
     console.log(response);
   });
```

Comment: Have a look at [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). You can do someting like `<select ng-options="message for message in messages" ng-model="selected"></select>` and when the server responds set `$scope.selected = response.data.data.message_page`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show selected value based on the certain condition you have to use ng-selected directive.

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue">
 <option ng-selected="myVar">Message1</option>
 <option >Message2</option>
 <option>Message3</option>    
</select>
```

it binds the value to UI and not to the ng-model, you have to bind the value from the controller if you want to bind it to ng-model.
The ng-selected directive is necessary to be able to shift the value between true and false.

controller.js

```
if(servermessage=="message1"){
  $scope.myVar=true;
  $scope.selectedValue="67";
}else{
  $scope.myVar=false;
}
```